# Kivy - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, kivy

Getting this error when attempting to run Kivy project with Python v3.9.7:

```
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] Kivy: v2.0.0
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] Factory: 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] Window: Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] App: Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Here is an output when running in Anaconda with Python v3.7.4:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\willi\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-09-27_1.txt
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] deps: Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] Kivy: v2.0.0
[INFO   ] Kivy: Installed at "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] Python: v3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] Python: Interpreter at "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
```

In the Anaconda environment it executed just fine, so I came to the conclusion that it must be something to do with the Python version perhaps? I couldn't find anything online that detailed anyone else having this problem. I did not have this issue in the past with Python v3.9.1

> So why don't you just use the Anaconda environment since it works fine there?

The reason being is that I am using Spyder and after executing the Kivy program using the kernel there and closing the window, it always freezes the kernel and I have to force-quit and start another. So it is annoying and inconvenient.

**Things that I have tried**

1. uninstall / reinstall Kivy
2. uninstall / reinstall kivy.deps.sdl2

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Python ? If yes and it still doesn't, maybe one alternative is to install the latest development version of Kivy from [the kivy repo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy)? I have a friend who got the same error and when he tried both of those it worked for him.

Comment: So I'm not sure if it is because I'm new to stackoverflow or what but I can't seem to upvote or check your answer, but this is the solution that worked for me so thanks!

Comment: It's because this is a comment, not an answer because I don't feel like sending it as an answer if it can fit perfectly in a comment haha. I'm glad that this helps, though!